# In Python, how do I calculate the circumference of a list of radii?

Tags: python

I am writing a program where I need to calculate the circumference, area, and volume of a list of radii. The program should prompt the user to enter a choice of 1, 2, or 3. Choice 1 should calculate and display
the circumferences, choice 2 for areas and 3 for volumes. Any other input should display a message
“Invalid response!”.

At this moment, I'm strictly focusing on getting the circumference down before I move onto the area and volume. What I'm struggle with is how to create a loop that will traverse the list of radii and allow me to print off the circumference of all the numbers in the list. I have tried researching this topic and have only found tutorials on how to calculate the circumference of a circle in python, rather than from a list in python.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
def main():
  import math
    radii_list = [3.2, 6.7, 12.6]
    for radii in radii_list:
        circumference = radii * 2 * math.pi
        area = (radii^2) * math.pi
        volume = (4/3)*(radii^3) * math.pi
    print("Choose one of these options:")
    print("1. Circumference\n2. Area\n3. Volume")
    num = input(">> ")
    if num == 1:
        print(circumference)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When I run the program, however, the program simply stops after I enter 1:

Choose one of these options:

1. Circumference
2. Area
3. Volume

Could anyone help guide me in the right direction?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Forget about the radii and all that. You just need to know how to respond to input.

Comment: Does anyone know how print out the circumference for each radii in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are taking input to check the user input to show result realetd to area vol, circumference, that input type is `str` and you are comparing it as int type, you need to change the `num` to `int` type as `num = int(input())` , rest is chose a way to save all the result related to a radii in a list and then print it in accordance with the user input

```
def main():
    import math
    radii_list = [3.2, 6.7, 12.6]
    res = {'cir':[], 'area':[], 'vol':[]}
    for radii in radii_list:
        res['cir'].append(radii * 2 * math.pi)
        res['area'].append((radii**2) * math.pi)
        res['vol'].append((4/3)*(radii**3) * math.pi)
    print("Choose one of these options:")
    print("1. Circumference\n2. Area\n3. Volume")
    num = int(input(">> "))
    if num == 1:
        print(res['cir'])
    elif num==2:
        print(res['area'])
    elif num==3:
        print(res['vol'])
    else:
        print("invalid input")
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to print these off without using the brackets format? I'm trying have it print out in a format that will have both the original three radii listed vertically and then have the circumference for each radii on the opposite side.

Comment: if you mean from `[1,2,3]` to `1 2 3` then just do `print(*res['cir'])`

Comment: That answers part of my question. I'm also trying to print the numbers vertically.

Comment: use seperator, `print(*res['cir'], sep='\n')`

Comment: Any way to print out both the radii from the list and the circumference side by side?

Comment: `for radii, cir in zip(radii_list, res['cir']): print(radii, cir, sep='\t')`

Comment: You are awesome! Thank you so much for your help

Comment: if the solution helps you, you can accept the solution

Answer (score 2):

OK, here are a few thoughts:

1. The `import` belongs at the top of the file, not in the `main` function. That's not the problem, but it's how python works.
2. do you know the type you're getting for `num`? You can check with `type(num)`.
3. In the `if`, you might add an `else` block. if it prints, say, the `type` and value of `num`, you will find out a little more about what your program is doing.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `input(">> ")` will always give you a str, so `input(">> ") == 1`, will never be true, you should convert to a int, like: `int(input(">> "))`. Also in python use `**` instead of ^.

```py
def main():
    import math
    radii_list = [3.2, 6.7, 12.6]
    for radii in radii_list:
        circumference = radii * 2 * math.pi
        area = (radii**2) * math.pi
        volume = (4/3)*(radii**3) * math.pi
    print("Choose one of these options:")
    print("1. Circumference\n2. Area\n3. Volume")
    num = int(input(">> "))
    if num == 1:
        print(circumference)
    elif num == 2:
        print(area)
    elif num == 3:
        print(volume)
    else:
        print("Option Not Found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the comments, the OP asked to print the area for each radii.

Code:

```py
def main():
    import math
    radii_list = [3.2, 6.7, 12.6]
    for radii in radii_list:
        circumference = radii * 2 * math.pi
        area = (radii**2) * math.pi
        volume = (4/3)*(radii**3) * math.pi
        print("Choose one of these options:")
        print("1. Circumference\n2. Area\n3. Volume")
        num = int(input(">> "))
        if num == 1:
            print(circumference)
        elif num == 2:
            print(area)
        elif num == 3:
            print(volume)
        else:
            print("Option Not Found")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you KetZoomer. However, it is still not printing anything.

Comment: Thanks! That was a massive help

Comment: How do you print out the circumferences for each radii?

Comment: Now it is only printing out the circumference for the first radii

Answer (score 1):

```
import math


def main():
    radii_list = [3.2, 6.7, 12.6]
    for radii in radii_list:
        circumference = radii * 2 * math.pi
        area = (radii**2) * math.pi
        volume = (4/3)*(radii**3) * math.pi
    print("Choose one of these options:")
    print("1. Circumference\n2. Area\n3. Volume")
    num = int(input(">> "))
    if num == 1:
        print(circumference)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In other notes, while using python 3+
`^` is an unsupported operand for 'float' and 'int'

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Do you know how to print off the circumference of every radii?

Answer (score -1):

The input of python will store input as a string, not an integer.
Try using

```
if num == "1":
    print(...)
```